# DL QUERY : Pizza Ontology : Is there a way to get the toppings ON the pizza?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, protege, dlquery

I'm extremely new to protoge' and I've been playing around with the pizza ontology.

I know how to get the list of pizza's that contain a certain number or type or toppings but how do I do it the OTHER way around?

How do I get a list of toppings that a certain pizza has? Or do I have to use SPARQL for such a query?

For example: All the toppings on an American Pizza.

I tried "isToppingOf some American" and it doesn't seem to be working.

I had thought that it should work since isToppingOf is the inverse of hasTopping..but maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this homework for a class?  There have been some very similar questions in the past. The one I linked to above was asked just about a year ago (beginning of the school year).  In general, the query you're describing is not possible, but you can get *some* of the information that you want (see the linked question).  SPARQL could be used here to get some information, but not necessarily everything that you'd want.

Comment: Inverse properties work as you might expect for *individuals* and not for concepts. So if you are talking about an individual pizza, and individual toppings, you can do this with reasoning. Otherwise, I don't think reasoner inferencing will help.

Comment: @PhilLord (I think I may be reiterating what you're saying, but to clarify...) Inverse properties work in exactly the same fashion, but while it's true that "American subclassof (hasTopping some CheeseTopping)" because *every* American pizza has some cheese topping, it's *not* true that "CheeseTopping subclassof ((inverse hasTopping) some American)" because it's not the case that every cheese topping is on some American pizza.  It's not really an issue with inverse properties so much as that "every american pizza has cheese" is simply not equivalent to "all cheese is on american pizza."

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late reply! 

@JoshuaTaylor , I actually found that thread after I posted this even though I searched through the sections before. I may have missed it somehow.

Anyway, the reason I left this open was because I wondered if someone could help me figure out HOW to get that sort of result set if absolutely needed.

And no, this is not an assignment lol. It's just that we use the pizza ontology as a basis to learn, so perhaps a lot of us our mapping are own ontology to the pizza ontology and trying to figure stuff out (that's what I'm doing at least :P )

Comment: @PoRco1x "HOW to get that sort of result set" How to get *what* sort of result set?